# Comparing 2 XML files and getting all parent nodes

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I'am using XMLUnit to compare two XML files(the only difference is in version):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

with a code which you can see below:

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
DetailedDiff diff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(getGoodXML(), getWrongXML()));

List<Difference> allDiifferences= diff.getAllDifferences();
    for(Difference in : allDiifferences){
        System.out.println("VALUE1("+in.getControlNodeDetail().getValue()+")  VALUE2("+in.getTestNodeDetail().getValue()+")");
    }
```

Right now I get all differences between those two XML files. My goal is to get the whole path to those different elements. I should be able to get something like this:

```
/dependency/version/ VALUE1(1.4) VALUE2(1.5)
```

I suppose there is a better way to get the whole path than using something like this:

```
Node previousNode = in.getControlNodeDetail().getNode.getParentNode()
```

I am looking for a method which get all previous node names.
Any hints?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `in.getControlNodeDetail().getXpathLocation()`?

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for! :) (I have no idea how I could missed it)